# Ti.Network.createHTTPClient async

Tags: android, ios, http, asynchronous, titanium

I have the need to download data from a web server at startup of the app . The data is to be retrieved from a 50 http addresses . The problem that I load the page of the app before it has completed the recovery operation via http request of titanium . Do you have any suggestions?

```
function doRequest(url, callback) {
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onerror: function (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    },
    onload: function () {
        try {
            callback(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
        catch (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
    }
});

client.open('GET', url);
client.send();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use promises.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Look at documentation on `all` or `sequences`

```
return Q.all([
    download(url1),
    download(url2)
    ...
]);
```